# How can I add all of the partials under a directory to another partial view dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AngularJS, and have started creating directive templates, etc, in MVC partial views.

I want to combine all of these partials (there are several, including some nested in folders below) into a single partial that I can call to load all of the templates at once.

Because there are so many, adding them via `@html.Partial('bla')` manually would be cumbersome.

Is there a way I can declare the "parent" partial such that it will iterate the available partials under a given directory and add them all?

Comment: You can get the file list in your view folder and loop through them. Dirty but works. Not from what I know if there's any better and cleaner way.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I wonder if I can use MVC bundling.  Technically the templates are in script tags anyways, but as long as I don't minify...maybe that would work?

Comment: No, bundling won't work. @tweray's suggestion is pretty much all you can do. However, consider that partials are not free, and if you're rendering hundreds of them in a single view, it *will* affect the performance your site.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, can you elaborate on why bundling won't work? Can it not be extended somehow to shoehorn this behavior? You're right to point out the performance impact.  In my case Angular will lazy load my templates as necessary and we'll use AppCache to cache the parent partial on the client for subsequent loads.

Comment: Because it's not designed to do this. For one, it doesn't handle HTML, and it especially doesn't handle *views* in the sense where you'd need to let Razor process it first. And, even if you could hack it to include such functionality, you're tightly coupling functionality. For example, the bundler is designed to bundle in production but not in development. But, if you used it for this, you'd have to bundle *always* in order to have this function in development, which then makes it nigh impossible to actually debug your JS and CSS any more.

Comment: Just because you can hammer a nail with a shoe doesn't make the shoe a hammer.

Comment: @GrantH. is all your partials pure html or they have any razor code running? If they are all pure html, then you should consider write your own helper method to bind them as string and avoid using `@Html.Partial`. Each of `@html.Partial` will be a razor code compile and they are expensive.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, thanks for the response, that's helpful

Comment: @tweray, they should pretty much always be pure html, so you're right, that may be a viable option.  I'm also currently looking at a library called Cassette that may help with this specific need.